# why worker role instance is busy?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I am learning Azure cloud services.
I deployed the Contosco cloud service (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started/)
to a staging slot.
The Ads worker role instance is having problems (busy status).

Any tips on troubleshooting ? Clicking on the instance just shows high level info.
In a non-azure application, looking at event log would be useful. Should I following this instruction : https://www.opsgility.com/blog/2011/09/20/windows-event-logs-with-windows-azure-diagnostics-and-powershell/

Thanks,Peter

Comment: could you add your worker role code?

Answer (score 0):

You should first check [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-role-lifecycle-dotnet/) link to understand the various lifecycles a cloud service goes through. My understanding is something written in onstart() method might be the cause, but without any code in the question I can't be sure. Then you can Enable Diagnostics (logs) using [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-diagnostics-for-cloud-services-and-virtual-machines/) and [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/) links. So, that you clearly see, what line of code has executed and what is keeping the cloud service busy.